# Linking Tables Together

Tags: sql-server

If I have a table such as this,

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[StreetLight](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Description] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Shape] [geometry] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_StreetLight] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]

GO
```

What structure is ideal to use to relationally link street lights together. For instance I have street light 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, and I want to say that street light 6 and 2 are related. They might be on the same street for instance.

What are the ways I can do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would recommend adding another table, `StreetLightGrouping`. This table should have two columns, `StreetLightGroupId` and `StreetLightId`.  All the `StreetLights` under one `StreetLightGroupId` are part of the same group.

Also, if a `StreetLight` can belong to a maximum of one group, a unique constraint can be established on the `StreetLightId` column.

Comment: Right on the money. It might seem like a basic question, but if you look at my other questions lately it is part of a much bigger problem. Turns out that badly structured data i.e. non relational can confuse SQL server and it creates silly query plans which makes a query that runs instantly turn into one that hasn't finished after 10 minutes.